# PHPMailer and TLS configuration

Tags: amazon-web-services, phpmailer, tls1.2, amazon-ses

PHPMailer is working perfectly with SES in our Windows Server, but I received a notification from AWS about TLS 1.0 connections that need to be updated to TLS 1.2 or higher. Will this requirement affect PHPMailer?

I just need information about how this could affect us, and what to I have to do in case there is something to do.

Answer (score 0):

PHPMailer relies on the underlying openssl extension in your PHP runtime for its TLS support. Openssl has supported TLSv1.2 since version 1.0.1, released in 2012. You can check the version of openssl that your PHP is using with [the `phpinfo()` function](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.phpinfo), or displaying the value of the `OPENSSL_VERSION_TEXT` predefined constant.

Essentially, if you're using a current version of PHP, you will have support for TLSv1.2 and probably 1.3 as well, and you are unlikely to have any issues with the change AWS mentions – they are only saying it to alert those that are running *really* old systems.

Comment: Thank you very much, I find the following: openssl version text: OpenSSL 1.1.1s 1 Nov 2022. I have PHP 7.4.33. Can you guide me on what do I have to do? It's installed on Windows Server 2016. Thanks in advance

Comment: You should not have to do anything; You have a recent enough TLS version for 1.2 to work. Aside from that, both PHP 7.4 and Windows Server 2016 are considered outdated, so you should be planning to update both.

Comment: I'm in that tank you very much